# stop dispatch_time_t when a button is clicked

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i am implementing a simple dispatch timer to execute a few lines of code after two minutes of invocation of the timer. the code is as follows,

```
dispatch_time_t poptime = dispatch_time (DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds *NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(poptime,dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

              //some code here
});
```

what i am looking for is to either kill or stop or modify the timer to infinity when a button is clicked. i have the button click function and this dispatch timer is written in viewdidload function of class.

Is this possible? please help 
thanks.

Comment: This might help: http://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2011/12/cancel-dispatch_after/

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a two-minute NSTimer, then invalidate it when the button is clicked?

Comment: @James i tried NSTimer but it kinda stops the entire process and waits for the interval of time

Comment: How did you try using NSTimer? Something like this works for me and has never stopped the process: NSTimer *delay = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:120.0 target:self selector: @selector(callThisWhenTimeElapsed) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];

Answer (score 2):

Once a GCD block has been dispatched, you can't cancel it. You should use something like `NSTimer` instead.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK I know you can't do it with GCD.

Use: [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) instead and use `cancelAllOperations` for cancelling the operations.